# cache a canvas in an object (in memory)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, canvas, clone

I am trying to cache the different states a user sets for a canvas,

The thing is that using `.push` and `canvas.clone()` when I append it later it's same size, but white; without the image that it was showing,

Any posible way to store a `canvas` in memory?

-EDIT-

This is how I'm trying

```
effectosFotos: function ($foto) {
        var t;
        var selector = '#'+$foto.attr('id');
        var $foto = $(selector);
        var $backup = $foto.clone();
        var times = 0;
        var cached = [];

        $('.filters').show();

    var img1 = document.createElement('img');
    img1.onload = function () {
        var width1 = $('.filters li').eq(0).width()/3;
        var height1 = this.height*(width1/this.width);

        console.log(width1, height1);

        var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
        canvas1.width = width1;
        canvas1.height = height1;

            ctx1.drawImage(this, 0, 0, width1, height1);
        var newUrl = canvas1.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);
        $('.filters li a').each(function() {
                $(this).append( '<img id="preview_'+$(this).data('id')+'" src="'+newUrl+'">'  );  
        });



        $('.filters li a').each(function(i) {
                var $this = $(this);
                t = setTimeout(function () {
                    var effect = $this.data('id');
                    var $img = $('#preview_'+effect);
                    //console.log('Item='+i +' About to render '+ effect +' and exists? ' + $img.length );
                    Caman('#preview_'+effect, function () {
                        this[effect]();
                        this.render(function(){
                                 //console.log('rendered '+effect);
                                 $this.parent().addClass('rendered');
                        });
                    }); 

                }, 1*i)


        });
    }
        img1.src = $foto.attr('src');       

        $('.filters').on('click', 'li:not(.active) a', function(e){
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var $this = $(this).addClass('loading');
            $this.parent().addClass('loading');


            e.preventDefault();
            var effect = $(this).data('id');
            var parent = $(selector).parent();
            //console.log('f'+$(selector).length, effect,times,$(selector).prop("tagName"),$backup.prop("tagName"));
            /*if(times == 0){
                    $backup = $foto.clone();
            }
            times++;*/
            $(selector).remove();
            parent.append($backup);
            console.log(cached);

            var found = -1;
            for ( var c = 0; c < cached.length; c++ ) {
                var item = cached[c];
                if ( item.effect == effect ) {
                    found = c;
                } 
            }
            if (effect == 'normal'){
                $(selector).css('opacity',1);
                $this.parent().addClass('active').removeClass('loading').siblings().removeClass('active');
            } else if ( found > -1 ) {



            console.log('Cargamos caché  ' + effect + ' a '+width +'x'+height);
            var canvas = document.getElementById($foto.attr('id'))
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx3 = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx3.clearRect(  0, 0, width, height );
            ctx3.drawImage( cached[found].canvas, 0, 0);
            $this.parent().addClass('active').removeClass('loading').siblings().removeClass('active');
      } else  {
            $(selector).remove();
            parent.append($backup);
            $(selector).css('opacity',0.3); 
            $('.takePictureHolder').addClass('caming');
            Caman(selector, function () {
                this[effect]();
                this.render(function(){
                    $(selector).css('opacity',1);  
                    $this.parent().addClass('active').removeClass('loading').siblings().removeClass('active');
                    $('.takePictureHolder').removeClass('caming');
                    if (found == -1) {
                        var canvas = document.getElementById($foto.attr('id'));
                        var clone = canvas.cloneNode(true);
                           clone.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0,0);
                        cached.push({ 'effect' :effect, "canvas":clone });
                        /*var ctx4 = document.getElementById($foto.attr('id')).getContext('2d');
                        console.log('Cacheamos ' + effect + ' a '+width +'x'+height);
                        cached.push({ 'effect' :effect, "canvas":ctx4.getImageData(0,0,width, height) });*/
                    }
                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = end - start;
                    console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
                }); 
            });         
        }       
        });
    }
```

Comment: How about [`getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) ? I guess `clone` will store the `DOM object` in array but not pixels in it!

Comment: is there any chance we could get a simple jsFiddle example?

Comment: @Canvas it's not really my position, but this reproduces it http://jsfiddle.net/Sv87G/3207/

Comment: What do you mean by "different states"? It's usually easier to save all the commands the user has demanded rather than saving the current canvas content (as an image or as a pixel-array).

Comment: Differents effects that user applies to an image, so he want's to see again, I don't have to reprocess the image... I wan't to write the final version only. But the reason is not important for this question, is it?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet. Yep, it's important. If your "effects" are easily reproducible (like adding annotating text or paths or even compositing), a more efficient solution is to record the context commands that created your effect rather than saving the completed effect. The notable exception is compound image filtering (f.ex: grayscaling then bluring then gradient masking) which might take more time & resources to reproduce. :-)

Comment: But at the end, I want the final image. And I don't want to user to wait for generation of an effect he already used..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet. Ok, If you don't want to explain what "states" and "effects" means then I give up on a detailed answer. :-// As a general rule, It's memory inefficient to make copies of the canvas to save its interim content. Poor memory management is a disservice to your users. Instead, it's almost always more efficient to save the commands that created the effect and "replay" them to recreate the effect. Anyway, good luck with your project. :-)

Comment: perhaps do you know camanjs? this plugin has presets, with states I mean that. And i want to export the final result to an image. but if he's choosing filters, they have to be calculated everytime (and they take nearly a minute!), i just want to be calculated once; the rest times, from the backup....

Comment: Edited with my current try... in case it helps @markE

Comment: If you are applying expensive image filters then you should go with @Kaiido's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and way more efficient than export methods is to draw your to-be-saved canvas on a clone, using `clonedCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0)`. You will then be able to store the cloned canvas in an array :

Andreas' snippet with modified code :

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    states = [];

console.log('setup states...');
setupState();


function rndColor() {
    var rgb = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
    }
    
    return "rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")";
}

function setupState() {
    canvas.width = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    canvas.height = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    context.fillStyle = rndColor();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var clone = canvas.cloneNode(true);
    clone.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0,0);
    states.push(clone)

    if (states.length < 5) {
        setTimeout(setupState, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("restore states...");
     setTimeout(restoreStates, 2000);
    }
}

function restoreStates() {
    var state = states.shift();
    
    canvas.width = state.width;
    canvas.height = state.height;
    
    context.clearRect(0, 0, state.width, state.height);
    context.drawImage(state, 0, 0);
    
    if (states.length) {
        setTimeout(restoreStates, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: solid 5px blue }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But, as pointed out by @markE, if you need to store a lot of these states *(e.g if you want to implement an undo/redo feature)*, it can quickly fill all your memory.

Then the recommended way is to save all drawing operations and reapply them.   Still using Andreas' snippet, a minimal implementation could be :

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    states = [];

console.log('setup states...');
setupState();


function rndColor() {
    var rgb = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
    }
    
    return "rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")";
}

function setupState() {
    // create an object with all our states settings and operations
    var state = {fillStyle: rndColor(), width: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), height:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)};
    // save the operations in an array
    state.operations = [{name:'fillRect',arguments: [0,0,state.width, state.height]}];
    // save the state
    states.push(state);
    // parse it a first time;
    parse(state);
  
    if (states.length < 5) {
        setTimeout(setupState, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("restore states...");
     setTimeout(restoreStates, 2000);
    }
}

function parse(state){
    // restore our canvas and context's properties
    // this could be improved by creating canvas and context objects in our state and then restore the corresponding with a for(x in y) loop
    canvas.width = state.width;
    canvas.height = state.height;
    context.fillStyle = state.fillStyle;
    // retrieve the operations we applied
    var op = state.operations;
    // loop through them
    for(var i=0; i<op.length; i++){
      // check it actually exists as a function
      if(typeof context[op[i].name]==='function')
        // apply the saved arguments
        context[op[i].name].apply(context, op[i].arguments);
      }
  }

function restoreStates() {
    var state = states.shift();
    parse(state);
    if (states.length) {
        setTimeout(restoreStates, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: solid 1px blue }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: IMHO, I would hesitate to **generally** recommend creating many copies of a canvas in various states of progress. My concern is about ever expanding memory & resource usage. The one exception would be if the canvas has expensive image filters applied that would take equal resources to reproduce -- and that may be the case here (but the OP is coy about saying what "effects" are applied). Just my 2-cents. :-)

Comment: @markE I absolutely agree with that, and will edit my post to reflect that. Just posted it to avoid the `getImageData`/`postImageData` be the only solution provided, when `clonedCtx.drawImage(canvas, x,y)` is way lighter in term of process. Also, if OP needs only to save the canvas at one state, to reuse it later, it may be over-complicating to save all drawing operations.

Comment: Chuckle!  Looks like they are indeed applying expensive image filters...so I like your answer!

Comment: Your first fiddle works great, at least the concept, but for some reason; when restoring a state, the result is a cropped version of the state; any idea why? (I mean width and height variables are global to de function..) (edited code in my question)

Comment: My fault, i wan't using the width and the height clonedCtx.drawImage(canvas, x,y) -> clonedCtx.drawImage(canvas, x,y, width, height)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, I'm not sure I can decipher your code just by reading it, but if you did set `canvas` `.width` and `.height` properties, `canvas.cloneNode(true).getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, x, y)` should be enough. I'm wondering if you're clones are not getting saved at a wrong size

Comment: they wasn't, it was a restore; I was specifying canvas dimensions but now drawimage dimensions.. Any way; thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You could save the content of the canvas with [`.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setImageData).
And [`.putImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) for restoring the old content.

```js
var data = [];

// store canvas/image
data.push(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));


// restore canvas/image
var oldData = data.pop();

canvas.width = oldData.width;
canvas.height = oldData.height;
context.clearRect(oldData, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.putImageData(oldData, 0, 0);
```

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    states = [],
    img;

console.log("setup states...");
setupState();


function rndColor() {
    var rgb = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
    }
    
    return "rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")";
}

function setupState() {
    canvas.width = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    canvas.height = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    context.fillStyle = rndColor();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    states.push(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));

    if (states.length < 5) {
        setTimeout(setupState, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("restore states...");
     setTimeout(restoreStates, 2000);
    }
}

function restoreStates() {
    var state = states.shift();
    
    canvas.width = state.width;
    canvas.height = state.height;
    
    context.clearRect(0, 0, state.width, state.height);
    context.putImageData(state, 0, 0);
    
    if (states.length) {
        setTimeout(restoreStates, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: solid 5px blue }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The same would be possible with [`.toDataUrl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
and [`.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)
But this would be the slower approach: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/testing-getimagedata-and-todataurl/3) (at least in chrome)

```js
var images = [];

// store canvas/image
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
images.push(img);


// restore canvas/image
var oldImage = images.pop();

canvas.width = oldImage.width;
canvas.height = oldImage.height;
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0);
```

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    states = [],
    img;

console.log("setup states...");
setupState();


function rndColor() {
    var rgb = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
    }
    
    return "rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")";
}

function setupState() {
    canvas.width = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    canvas.height = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    context.fillStyle = rndColor();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    states.push(img);

    if (states.length < 5) {
        setTimeout(setupState, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("restore states...");
     setTimeout(restoreStates, 2000);
    }
}

function restoreStates() {
    var state = states.shift();
    
    canvas.width = state.width;
    canvas.height = state.height;
    
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(state, 0, 0);
    
    if (states.length) {
        setTimeout(restoreStates, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: solid 5px blue }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Encoding the image in a string sounds horribly inefficient.

Comment: @Bergi You're right: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/testing-getimagedata-and-todataurl/3). I've added a solution without encoding as string.